# Django Model IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: python, django

I am building a service that makes short URLs. I have the models:

```
from django.db import models

class ShortURL(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class LongURL(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True)
    url_to_short = models.ForeignKey(ShortURL)
```

I have already run the command: `python manage.py migrate`
If I open the interpreter, using `python manage.py shell` and run this code:

```
>>> from appshort.models import LongURL
>>> a = LongURL(name = 'hello_long_link')
>>> a.save()
```

then I get the error:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: appshort_longurl.url_to_short_id`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `url_to_short` FK field is required on your model but you forgot to fill it.

Comment: You create a `LongURL` without giving it a `ShortURL`, which is an error. If that's a valid case, make the `ShortURL` field optional as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619984/can-i-make-the-foreign-key-field-optional-in-django-model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class LongURL(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True)
    url_to_short = models.ForeignKey(ShortURL)
```

The way you have set it up, the `url_to_short` foreign key is *not optional*.  So when you try to save:

```
>>> a = LongURL(name = 'hello_long_link')
>>> a.save()
```

Django is trying to tell you that you didn't provide the `url_to_short` relation on your `a` model instance.

You'll need to either

- Provide the ShortURL relation when you create the `LongURL` instance
- Make the `url_to_short` relation optional with `null=True, blank=True`.

Comment: this is especially confusing since I have another example where `default=None` worked in the same situation, but now it seems that `null=True, blank=True` is required (?).

Answer (score 0):

While creating an entry for `LongURL` you must create an object of `ShortURL` or filter out already existing (because `ForeignKey` field cannot be left blank). Additionally, you say that sometimes you have been able to achieve the desired behaviour. This can be so because at those places you would have got an object of `ShortURL` which is **not** `null`. However, the error in the discussion arises, when you try to send a null object during the creation of `LongURL`. For example:

```
...
short_url_obj = ShortURL.objects.filter(...).first()
# you have to ensure that this above query is not null
try: 
    new_long_url = LongURL(url_to_short=short_url_obj, name="some_name")
    new_long_url.save()

except:
    # if the short_url_obj is null
    print("The short_url_obj was null, cannot save to database")

...
```

One can also use `if-else` block instead, but I would not advice that.